# Remove specific string of data with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a unusual instance where an application is generating a string of data but is adding a suffix code at the end of string surrounded by parentheses. I need to find the best javascript method to remove the parentheses and data that is in it. One key thing is this string can be different but will always have the parentheses around the specific data that needs to be removed.

```
Anything in the parenthesis.

Example 
STR-STOOL RAW (STR)

Needs to be 
STR-STOOL RAW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "STR-STOOL RAW (STR)";
var newStr = str.replace(/ \(.*\)/,'');
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, now I understand regex method better now with this example.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/\(.*\)$/
```

- **`\(`** and **`\)`** matches the parenthesis
- **`.*`** matches any character
- `$` is necessary to meet at the end of the expression.

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/iT5dY9)

```
var result = "(STR) STR-STOOL RAW (STR)".replace(/\(.*\)$/g,""); //outputs (STR) STR-STOOL RAW
```

In the above example only the last `(STR)` is replaced

Comment: The global flag makes no sense here.

Comment: totally agree let me remove it. Thanks for highlighting it

Comment: The global flag didn't work, I used the other method .replace(/ \(.*\)/,'') and this works great.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me specially if your line has existing parentheses
`\([^\)]*\)$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hK5dV2)